# Installing gdcm to CentOS 7

Tags: linux, gdcm

I am a beginner about compiling from source, so I need your help!

As I need to execute gdcmdump on CentOS 7, I am trying to install gdcm.

First I tried to

`git clone --branch release git://git.code.sf.net/p/gdcm/gdcm`

but it failed. So I cloned the release by

`git clone https://git.code.sf.net/p/gdcm/gdcm gdcm-gdcm`

and did

`mkdir gdcmbin
 cd gdcmbin
 cmake ../gdcm
 make
 make install`

without any errors.

But somehow I cannot execute gdcmdump. ("command not found" shown)

I also tried another option (I'm not sure it is actually right):

I downloaded GDCM-3.0.5-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz from
https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM/releases/tag/v3.0.5
and unzipped it.

I found "bin", "include", "lib", "share" directories in it.
But I have no idea how to handle these...

Any comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`make` creates the executable locally, so if it's not in your `$PATH`, you'll have to provide a path to it. You could instead use `make install` (requires root permissions) to install it for all users.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
Oops, I'm sorry, I dropped it from my description. (I've edited my question above.)
Actually I did "make install", but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>.. somehow I cannot execute gdcmdump. "command not found"</sub>

Plain `cmake ..` will build "gdcm*Tests" only. See INSTALL.txt : <sub>GDCM_BUILD_APPLICATIONS: turn it on if you want the build gdcm applications (**gdcmdump**, gdcmconv, gdcminfo ...)</sub>.

GDCM-3.0.5.tar.gz https://codeload.github.com/malaterre/GDCM/tar.gz/v3.0.5

```
tar xvf GDCM-3.0.5.tar.gz
cd GDCM-3.0.5/ && mkdir build && cd build/
cmake -DGDCM_BUILD_APPLICATIONS:BOOL=ON ..
make
```

The executable's `gdcmanon, gdcmdiff, gdcmgendir, gdcminfo, gdcmraw, gdcmscu, gdcmxml, gdcmconv, gdcmdump, gdcmimg, gdcmpap3, gdcmscanner, gdcmtar` are created in `bin/`

---

About "GDCM-3.0.5-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz" : `$ cd GDCM-3.0.5-Linux-x86_64/bin/ && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../lib/ && ./gdcmdump` .... No issues.